# udev rule ownership

Tags: udev

Recently an udev rules was not executed. After some investigations, it was a symlink to a user file with these permissions : 
`-rw-r--r-- 1 user user`

changing ownership to `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root` and reloading indev rules with `udevadm control --reload` solved the problem.

I understand that for security reasons it is better to have system files owned by root. Does that mean udev checks rules owners and rejects non-root rules? Is there another explanation?

Comment: "A udev rule must not be writable to non-root user."